# K-value selection in KNN using simple dataset in R

Tags: r, algorithm, machine-learning, knn

I know this has been answered in many cases online, but since this is so datset dependent, I was wondering if there was a simple way of finding the best K-value in a KNN algorithm using a relatively simple dataset.

My response variable is a behavioural class (column E: Event) and my predictor variables are the three axis from an activity sensor (columns B to D). Here's a [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhQ9p.jpg) of how my data looks like.

Find below the code I've written to run my knn analysis. The `datanet` object looks just like the sample image I've uploaded. I'm using the first 150 rows as training, and the rest [151 to 240] of the rows as testing.

I've used a K-value of 10 in this case but after running the script for different K-values I obviously get different outputs, so was wondering what would be the best way to choose a K-value that is the most appropriate for my dataset. Specially, I need help for coding this in R.

```
library(data.table)

#From the file "Collar_#.txt", just select the columns ACTIVITY_X, ACTIVITY_Y, ACTIVITY_Z and Event
dataraw<-fread("Collar_41361.txt", select = c("ACTIVITY_X","ACTIVITY_Y","ACTIVITY_Z","Event"))

#Now, delete all rows containg the string "End"
datanet<-dataraw[!grepl("End", dataraw$Event),]

#Then, read only the columns ACTIVITY_X, ACTIVITY_Y and ACTIVITY_Z for a selected interval that will act as a trainning set
trainset <- datanet[1:150, !"Event"]
View(trainset)

#Create the behavioural classes. Note that the number of rows should be in the same interval as the trainset dataset
behaviour<-datanet[1:150,!1:3]
View(behaviour)

#Test file. This file contains sensor data only, and behaviours would be associated based on the trainset and behaviour datasets
testset<-datanet[151:240,!"Event"]
View(testset)

#Converting inputs into matrix
train = as.matrix(trainset, byrow = T, ncol=3)
test = as.matrix(testset, byrow = T, ncol=3)
classes=as.matrix(behaviour,byrow=T,ncol=1)

library(stats)
library(class)

#Now running the algorithm. But first we set the k value.

for kk=10

kn1 = knn(train, test, classes, k=kk, prob=TRUE)

prob = attributes(.Last.value)
clas1=factor(kn1)

#Write results, this is the classification of the testing set in a single column
filename = paste("results", kk, ".csv", sep="")
write.csv(clas1, filename)

#Write probs to file, this is the proportion of k nearest datapoints that contributed to the winning class
fileprobs = paste("probs", kk, ".csv", sep="")
write.csv (prob$prob, fileprobs)
```

I'm also uploading a sample [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rCRz.jpg) of the output of my script. See on the D column the "real behavioural class" for the values on the columns A to C, and on the columns E,G,I,K,M and O the classes assigned by the algorithm based on training from rows [1:150], for different K-values.

Any help is truly appreciated!!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with this package. Does it have a tune function where you could search for the best value?

Answer (score 1):

Find the `K` is not a easy mission in KNN, A small value of `K` means that noise will have a higher influence on the result and a large value make it computationally expensive.

I usually see people using: `K = SQRT(N)`. But, if you wan't to find better `K` to your cenario, use KNN from Carret package, here's one example:

```
library(ISLR)
library(caret)

# Split the data:
data(iris)
indxTrain <- createDataPartition(y = iris$Sepal.Length,p = 0.75,list = FALSE)
training <- iris[indxTrain,]
testing <- iris[-indxTrain,]

# Run k-NN:
set.seed(400)
ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",repeats = 3)
knnFit <- train(Species ~ ., data = training, method = "knn", trControl = ctrl, preProcess = c("center","scale"),tuneLength = 20)
knnFit

#Use plots to see optimal number of clusters:
#Plotting yields Number of Neighbours Vs accuracy (based on repeated cross validation)
plot(knnFit)
```

[image]

This shows 5 has the highest accuracy rate, so the value of `K` is 5.

Comment: Thank you. I've been running the script you provided with my data and seems to work:  
`indxTrain <- createDataPartition(y = datanet$Event,p = 0.65,list = FALSE)
training <- datanet[indxTrain,]
testing <- datanet[-indxTrain,]

set.seed(400)
ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",repeats = 3)
knnFit <- train(Event ~ ., data = training, method = "knn", trControl = ctrl, preProcess = c("center","scale"),tuneLength = 20)
[...]`
I would like to clarify 2 things: In your example, how was your data formated (picture/table?) and what are you classifying (species or sepal length)?

Comment: I'm asking since you used the subset `iris$Sepal.Length` in your `createDataPartition` function but then put `Species` as a response in your `train` function. So, what was you classifying out of those two characters? Maybe you was trying to classify `Species` based on `Sepal.Length` from the training?

Comment: i'm classifying Species based on Sepal.Length, datapartition only give me 75% of the sample to training set and 25% to testing set.

Comment: If you question it's solved don't forget to mark it as solved.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to classify `Event` based on three different categories which are `ACTIVITY_X`, `ACTIVITY_Y` and `ACTIVITY_Z`. I guess the right syntax is therefore to include the predictor variable as an argument of `createDataPartition` and the response variable when running the algorithm itself.

Comment: I've been trying to set this up on my script but I can't manage to get the correct syntax for my three predictors:  `indxTrain <- createDataPartition(y = datanet$ACTIVITY_X,ACTIVITY_Y,ACTIVITY_Z,p = 0.8,list = FALSE)` or `indxTrain <- createDataPartition(y = datanet$(ACTIVITY_X,ACTIVITY_Y,ACTIVITY_Z),p = 0.8,list = FALSE)`  Any idea on how to solve this? I've been trying with (), [] and without and still getting an error message.

Comment: `createDataPartition` doesn't work for multiple columns. When you create the partition you already have the other columns in `datanet[indxTrain,]`. First you create the partition for one column and after that you filter all the `datanet` table with the partition.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, I don't need to specifiy the column partition far all predictors right? By just creating a partition for one of them (let's say, `ACTIVITY_X`) all the `datanet` table will be filtered with that partition? The correct syntax I guess IT can just be `indxTrain <- createDataPartition(y = datanet$ACTIVITY_X,p = 0.8,list = FALSE)` then?

Comment: There's a sample in my main post of how the `datanet` table looks like by the way.. "Sample" is the name of the file in the second paragraph.